Is it legal to lie down in a moving vehicle?
There are many modes of transport where you can be transported while lying down flat. Trains, planes or boats all offer various services to this end.
I am however yet to find a mode of transport over land in Europe where this is the case (aside from ambulances).
Do traffic laws prohibit passengers from lying down while a vehicle is in transit?

Do you mean on top of a car  (strapped in or not strapped in)? In the bed of a flatbed or pickup truck (loose, or in a coffin)? In the back of a semi-cab? In the trailer of a tractor-trailer? In the back seat or passenger seat of a car? In the driver's seat of a car (self-driving v. non-self driving)? In an RV? In the cargo area of van? Some of these would be illegal, others might be legal. The laws are also probably not entirely uniform across Europe.

"on a vehicle" normally means outside of the interior of a vehicle, but this could be a English as a second language misunderstanding.

Trains usually move 'over land', I assume you mean transport on a road/ street?

In the US, team drivers will lie down in the sleeping area of the cab while in motion. Often the top bunk is against policy though.

germany
Passengers (and drivers) in a street vehicle (but for a bus with a standing transportation allowance) need to wear seatbelts (or be strapped in otherwise) according to StVO §21a. Lying in bed is not compatible with the seatbelt mandate - in an Emergency vehicle, you are strapped in for that reason.
All other cases of allowed non-secured transportation are not applicable.
